# Alphanumeric Keyboard input not working on downloaded .blend file

Tags: shortcut, blend-files

I just downloaded a .Blend file and the number and letter hotkeys are not working.  Things like the tab key still work.  I open other files that where already on my laptop and everything works just fine.  The file I downloaded is from my other computer and it works just fine on that computer with all the key input working but for some reason not when transferred. I have downloaded two versions of the same file, one with everything packed, and one just the file before packing.  Both files have the exact same problem.

I am using version 2.78.
my laptop should be fine, i7 processor, 12G ram, 64 bit operating system.

Comment: Can you add a link to the file in question?

Comment: Here it is http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=44061